# Is it possible to change image of cell without making a custom cell class?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview, cell

In Xcode, if say I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that has a `UIImageView` in it, I am used to making a custom cell class to access that `UIImage`. However, is this necessary? I am convinced that I don't have to make a custom cell class just to access a `UIImage`.

Would I have to do something like...

```
for var subview in cell.subviews
{
    if subview is UIImageView
    {
        subview = UIImageView()
        subview.image = //change image here
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never dig into the private subview structure of views. That implementation can change in any iOS update. That image view you are finding is there for other purposes.

`UICollectionViewCell` does not provide an image property that you can use. If you wish to show an image, create a custom cell class that contains your own `UIImageView` setup with your desired constraints. Use that image view, not one you happen to find by digging into the private subviews.

Provide a property in your custom cell class to make it simple to access that image view in the `cellForItemAt` method.

Comment: Thank you. It's kind of a bummer IMO that you have to make an entire class file just to access one image.

Answer (score -1):

If you are seriously opposed to subclassing the UICollectionViewCell, those objects have a [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview) property to which you could add an image. You could then call `cell.contentView.layer.contents = someImage.cgImage` and you don't then need to go mucking around with undocumented subviews.